# Стоит ли оставить запятую после слова "отчет", или заменить на другой знак препинания/перестроить фразу?

Tags: пунктуация

Обращение руководства — это то, без чего не обходится ни один годовой отчет, главный инструмент коммуникации с инвесторами и акционерами компании.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше перестроить фразу, иначе возникают побочные смыслы: "годовой отчёт - это главный инструмент" и "то, без чего не обходится годовой отчет, а также главный инструмент". Например, можно так:

> Обращение руководства — это главный инструмент коммуникации с
>   инвесторами и акционерами компании, без него не обходится ни один
>   годовой отчет.

Answer (score 2):

**Предложение корректно:**

Обращение руководства — это **то**, без чего не обходится ни один годовой отчет, главный **инструмент** коммуникации с инвесторами и акционерами компании.

В данном случае мы имеем однородные сказуемые ***то*** и ***инструмент***, связь бессоюзная.